# Proving Lagrange's Identity using integration by parts

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integration-by-parts, sturm-liouville

For a homework problem, I'm supposed to prove Lagrange's identity using integration by parts. That is, I'm supposed to show that

$uSv-vSu=\frac{1}{w}\frac{d}{dx}[p(uv'-u'v)]$

Where $S$ is a Sturm-Liouville operator, $p\in C^1[a,b]$, and $u,v\in C^2[a,b]$.

I *must* use integration by parts (followed by differentiation), but I have no idea what the "parts" are I need to integrate by parts.

Since this is a homework problem, please do *not* solve the whole problem. Please just help me get the integral set up. Thanks!

Comment: Write down two differential equations $Su=f$ and $Sv=f$. Multiply first by $v$ and second by $u$. Then manipulate second derivative term using differentiation of product of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming
$$
   Sf = -\frac{1}{w}\frac{d}{dx}\left(p(x)\frac{df}{dx}\right).
$$
The inner product is a weighted inner product with weight $w$. That suggests considering
$$
    \int (uSv) w dx = -\int u(pv')'dx \\
          = -u(pv')+\int u'(pv')dx \\
          = -u(pv')+\int(pu')v'dx \\
          = -u(pv')+(pu')v-\int(pu')'vdx \\
          = -u(pv')+(pu')v+\int (Su)vw dx \\
          = p(u'v-uv')+\int (Su)vwdx
$$